# Unable to mount webdav, no error messages

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, webdav

I' trying to mount a webdav service in Nautilus on Ubuntu 12.04. I originally had crash errors with tracker-miner-fs, but after updating to most resent build any attempt to connect still leaves me with a connecting message and no errors. I've let it sit for in excess of 15 min and it never connects and never gives an error message. What am I missing here?

Comment: This unanswered question is about Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL. OP hasn't signed on in 4+ years so responses to comments asking if it's been solved are unlikely. VTC as `not reproducible`.